# Console doesn't show pretty UTF-8 characters in Shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, console, utf-8

I want to write some pretty, special characters taken from Web in my Shell Console with echo command. I want to write, for example, ▲ character, but it shows me ��� character. How can I solve the problem? Thanks!

Note: When I run `locale` command, it shows these:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=az_AZ.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=az_AZ.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=az_AZ.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=az_AZ.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=az_AZ.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=az_AZ.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your terminal try to set the character encoding to Unicode (UTF-8):

[image]